# Rails3 + mysql2 gem, I get LibMYSQL.dll not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

Ok so when I'm running "rake db:create:all" I get this "libMYSQL.dll not found.." error. I had the same problem with older version of rails but it was easy to fix, just copy libmysql.dll to ruby/bin.

Well, with Rails 3 I tryed the same thing but it doesn't work.

Anyone with a solution?

Ruby on Rails 3.0.3
mysql2 0.2.6
Ruby 1.9.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work.

I've gotten this working myself; with the caveat that you need to have the version of libmysql.dll from the same version of MySQL as your server is running (otherwise you'll get random errors which will take you ages to figure out).

I know this isn't a terribly helpful answer. Are you sure that you've definitely copied the right file into the right folder?

Comment: Stephen Orr, actually you were right, I have copied wrong version of libMYSQL.dll. Now it works! Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, but it may help others:
Look for your version of libmysql arround [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/). Download the .zip and copy de libmysql.dll from lib to your ruby/bin